# Wordpress - Extending core blocks : Grab the color variables

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am following a tutorial (https://wholesomecode.net/add-sidebar-to-your-custom-wordpress-block-with-inspectorcontrols/) on how to extend core blocks. It shows how to create a custom Panel and has 2 custom fields: ‘Font’ + ‘Background’ color settings.

It works, but it’s grabbing the color hexcode instead of the color variables. The colors are defined in the theme.json file.

Is there a way to grab the color variable (ex. –wp–preset–color–orange) instead of the hexcode?

Below are the code.

block.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "attributes": {
        "blockTextColor": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "blockBackground": {
      "type": "string"
    },
      "blockText": {
        "default": "Wholesome Plugin – hello from the editor!",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "name": "spruce/sp-extend-core-plugin",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Extend Core Plugin",
    "category": "design",
    "icon": "admin-plugins",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "example": {},
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "sp-extend-core-plugin",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
}
```

edit.js:

```
 import { ContrastChecker, InspectorControls, PanelColorSettings,ColorPalette, RichText, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import { Panel, PanelBody, TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

import './editor.scss';


 export default function Edit( { attributes, isSelected, setAttributes } ) {
     const { blockBackground, blockTextColor, blockText } = attributes;
     return [
         <InspectorControls>
             <Panel>
                 <PanelBody
                     title={ __( 'Block Content Settings', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ) }
                     icon="admin-plugins"
                 >
                     <TextControl
                         label={ __( 'Example Meta', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ) }
                         help={ __( 'This is an example meta field.', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ) }
                         onChange={ ( blockText ) => setAttributes( { blockText } ) }
                         value={ blockText }
                     />
                 </PanelBody>
                 <PanelColorSettings
                     title={ __( 'Block Color Settings', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ) }
                     icon="art"
                     initialOpen={ false }
                     colorSettings={ [
                         {
                           value: blockTextColor,
                          onChange: ( blockTextColor ) =>  setAttributes( { blockTextColor} ),
                             label: __( 'Font Color', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' )
                         },
                         {
                             value: blockBackground,
                             onChange: ( blockBackground ) =>  setAttributes( { blockBackground } ),
                             label: __( 'Background Color', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ),
                         }
                     ] }>
                         <ContrastChecker
                             isLargeText="false"
                             textColor={blockTextColor}
                             backgroundColor={blockBackground}
                         />
                 </PanelColorSettings>
             </Panel>
         </InspectorControls>,
         <p
             { ...useBlockProps() }
             style={ {
                 backgroundColor: blockBackground,
                 color: blockTextColor,
             } }
         >
             <RichText
                 className="block__text"
                 keepPlaceholderOnFocus
                 onChange={ ( blockText ) => setAttributes( { blockText } ) }
                 placeholder={ __( 'Block Text', 'sp-extend-core-plugin' ) }
                 tagName="span"
                 value={ blockText }
             />
         </p>
     ];
 }
```

save.js:

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


 export default function save( { attributes } ) {
  const { blockBackground, blockTextColor, blockText } = attributes;
    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps.save() }
    style={ {
        backgroundColor: blockBackground,
        color: blockTextColor,
    } }
    >
            { blockText }
        </p>
    );
 }
```

index.js:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';


import './style.scss';

import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
         * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
} );
```

Thank you!